# How to rotate a SKSpriteNode using anchorpoint in Swift?

Tags: swift, rotation, skspritenode

I am very new to Swift and attempting to make my first iPhone game. The game consists of a pentagon (5 SKSpriteNode rectangle images) that rotate. I am trying to rotate each colored rectangle 72 degrees so that it is still a pentagon, but each color is now shifted over one.

How can I implement this using anchorpoints & rotations?

Here is the pentagon for reference (each rectangle named rect1, rect2, etc):
[pentagon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGp0d.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using SKAction.roateByAngle(radians: CGFloat,duration: NSTimeInterval) ?